# Grep regex treated as path

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a script, where I read strings from txt file, then assign it to $snmp_cred variable and then trying to strip ip address from strings, using grep, into another variable ($snmp_ip)

```
while read snmp_cred; do

echo appliance $ADDM_address and $snmp_cred 
snmp_ip=$(echo $snmp_cred | grep "/((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\d(?=@)/g")
echo IP for snmp community is $snmp_ip

done </tmp/input.txt
```

Content of input.txt file is:

```
a10networks/generic/1.3.6.1.4.1.22610.1.3.27_thunder_series4430s/10.72.168.33@public
a10networks/generic/1.3.6.1.4.1.22610.1.3.23_thunder_series1030s/172.17.48.24@public
a10networks/generic/1.3.6.1.4.1.22610.1.3.16_ax3200_12/10.251.1.101@public
```

The regex works in online regex editor, but fails into bash script. Bash output is:

```
++ echo $'a10networks/generic/1.3.6.1.4.1.22610.1.3.27_thunder_series4430s/10.72.168.33@public\r'
++ grep '/((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\d(?=@)/g'
+ snmp_ip=
+ echo IP for snmp community is
IP for snmp community is
```

can anyone point, what an I doing wrong?

Comment: First, you should try to echo `$snmp_cred` before you pipe it to `grep` : `snmp_ip=$(echo $snmp_cred | grep`...

Comment: Ok, have updated post with echo and new output.

Comment: Maybe you need `grep -P`? I think you also do not need `/.../g`, remove the slashes and `g` at the end. Or just `grep "((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)[0-9]@"`. You used `\d` that is not supported by POSIX regex.

Comment: When I grep with -P, I receive whole string. It not cuts IP address from string

Comment: ++ echo $'a10networks/generic/1.3.6.1.4.1.22610.1.3.27_thunder_serie‌​s4430s/10.72.168.33@‌​public\r' 
++ grep '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4‌​‌​][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][‌​0-‌​9]?)[0-9]@' 
grep: Invalid collation character

Comment: is this what you need? `grep -oP '.*/\K.*(?=@)' input.txt`

Comment: It returns in variable all IP-s from input.txt.

I need to assign to variable IP-s per string

Comment: oops, I should've been clearer.. does that grep command get you the IPs required? if so, you can modify your script according to your required output.. and it would be a good idea to post your expected output for given input, which removes the ambiguity arising from worded texts

Comment: Even if you can stick some bandaids on this to get it limping along, your approach is completely wrong, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons why. If you post the expected output given that input we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not getting the matched texts only, you do not really need the lookahead that the POSIX regex does not support. Also, note that `\d` is not supported by POSIX regex standard either. Also, `grep` pattern should not be placed inside regex delimiters.

If you still need to use your pattern (say, to also grab the matches), pass the `-oP` option use:

```
grep -oP "((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?[1-9]\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?[1-9]\d?)\d(?=@)"
```

And the [**online demo**](https://ideone.com/dPnCs8)

Comment: For first it gives error:
    appliance 172.22.90.240 and a10networks/generic/1.3.6.1.4.1.22610.1.3.27_thunder_series4430s/10.72.168.33@public
    ++ echo $'a10networks/generic/1.3.6.1.4.1.22610.1.3.27_thunder_series4430s/10.72.168.33@public\r'
    ++ grep '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4‌​][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-‌​9]?)[0-9]@'
grep: Invalid collation character
+ snmp_ip=

Comment: For second it does not cut IP address. Only the whole string:
appliance 172.22.90.240 and a10networks/generic/1.3.6.1.4.1.22610.1.3.27_thunder_series4430s/10.72.168.33@public
++ echo $'a10networks/generic/1.3.6.1.4.1.22610.1.3.27_thunder_series4430s/10.72.168.33@public\r'
++ grep -P '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\d(?=@)'
+ snmp_ip=$'a10networks/generic/1.3.6.1.4.1.22610.1.3.27_thunder_series4430s/10.72.168.33@public\r'

Comment: Please note, that I need \d(?=@) (or any equivalent) to find matches with @ after, but not include it into regex match itself.

Comment: Can you modify this grep to cut only IP from string - a10networks/generic/1.3.6.1.4.1.22610.1.3.6_ax1000/172.17.64.221@igupirej ?

Answer (score 0):

In this statement:

```
snmp_ip=$($snmp_cred | grep "/((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\d(?=@)/g")
```

you are just expanding the variable, without passing it to `grep`.
you need to either pass it to grep as an argument (in the form of a file redirection) or send it to greps STDIN.

this worked for me

```
#!/bin/bash

while read snmp_cred; do
    #echo appliance $ADDM_address and $snmp_cred 
    snmp_ip=$(grep -E -o "((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)@" <<< $snmp_cred)
    echo IP for snmp community is $snmp_ip
done <input.txt
```

output:

```
IP for snmp community is 10.72.168.33@
IP for snmp community is 172.17.48.24@
IP for snmp community is
```

Comment: From this output I need only last (10.72.168.33)
Is there any way  to find matches with @ after, but not include it into regex match itself (\d(?=@) (or any equivalent)?

Comment: @VasiliyVegas oh ok, I've updated my answer, but for some reason, the last IP address doesn't get matched.

Comment: the input seems well-defined, the two statements in while loop can be replaced by `sed -E 's|.*/(.*)@.*|IP for snmp community is \1|' <<< "$snmp_cred"`

Comment: Thanks! Your answer most usable in my situation. Just added snmp_ip=${snmp_ip%?} to cut "@"

Comment: @VasiliyVegas did you get the last line to print the IP address? I couldn't work out why it wasn't matching?